# Constructor fails on second time, but not first

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, this, instance

I have the following code:

```
var foo = function () {
    foo = this;
    foo.boo = function () {
        console.log("boo");
    }
}

var bar = new foo().boo();
var baz = new foo().boo();
```

This code executes the first creation of an instance of `foo`, but fails at the second with the following output:

```
boo
/Users/BaranSkistad/Code/example.js:9
var baz = new foo().boo();
          ^

TypeError: foo is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/BaranSkistad/Code/example.js:9:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)

    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:578:3
```

Why is this script failing? I know it has something to do with setting foo to `this` on line 2, instead of just using `this`,  but why is it problematic?

```
var foo = function () {
    self = this;
    self.boo = function () {
        console.log("boo");
    }
}

var bar = new foo().boo();
var baz = new foo().boo();
```

If I set `self` to equal `this`, it passes, why is this so?

Comment: you set the value of a global variable in your function definition, so when you call it the first time it changes foo to an object of a class instead of a class itself

Comment: where are you using `this` inside the function?

Comment: @brk I am setting `foo` to equal `this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the following line

```
foo = this;
```

The above line misses the variable declaration. So `foo` will refer to the global variable `foo` which is a constructor.When you call the function first time the line executes and `foo` is changed to `this`(instance of the `foo`)

In the second case the code also creates a global variable `self` which will be equal to `this`. But in that case it will not change constructor because the names are different.

The solution to this is to make `foo` a local variable by using `let`(or `const/var`).

```js
var foo = function () {
    let foo = this;
    foo.boo = function () {
        console.log("boo");
    }
}

var bar = new foo().boo();
var baz = new foo().boo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you have already got the answer , but you may not to explicitly set `this`. If you `console.log` inside `foo` function it will log an `object`. Instead you can just `return` an `object` which will have all the inner function

```js
var foo = function() {
  return {
    testVal: 5,
    boo: function() {
      console.log("boo ", this.testVal);
    }
  }
}

var bar = new foo().boo();
var baz = new foo().boo();
```

Comment: Is there a case where you can't explicitly set `this`?

Comment: `this` works differently in js & the value of `this` depends on the scenario.Setting `this` will just set the context. It is necessary to know why we need to explicitly set `this` before doing this

Comment: Returning an object from a constructor is not a good idea. It will ruin the purpose of constructor.\

Comment: @MaheerAli is it ok to explicitly set `this` inside a constructor?

Comment: @brk OP is not setting `this`. He is just using another variable which will refer this. And it is fine because still the variable will be instance of that constructor. I think it actually doesn't make much difference to directly use `this` or use a local variable which refers `this`